# Trying to decrypt with aes-256-gcm with php

Tags: php, encryption, aes-gcm

I wondered whether anyone can help,

I am using encryption method aes-256-gcm, I can encrypt, but cannot decrypt.

Below is my code, can anyone see where I'm going wrong

```
$textToDecrypt = $_POST['message'];
$password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
$method = 'aes-256-gcm'; 
$tag_length = 16;
$password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);
$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($textToDecrypt), $method, 
$password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag_length);
```

Encryption code

```
$textToEncrypt = $_POST['message'];
$password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
$method = 'aes-256-gcm'; 
$tag_length = 16;


$password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);



$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . 
chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . 
chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);


$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $method, 
$password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag_length));
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to save the GCM `tag` (HMAC) with the ciphertext and pass it to the decryption function. It is not saved for you automatically (you should also generate a good IV and store it with the ciphertext as well).

[openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) is specified as:

`string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $key [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" [, string &$tag = NULL [, string $aad = "" [, int $tag_length = 16 ]]]]] )`

If you look closely, you're passing in `$tag_length` where `$tag` is expected.

Here's how it should look like:

**Encryption:**

```
$textToEncrypt = $_POST['message'];
$password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);
$cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
$iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$tag_length = 16;
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);
$tag = ""; // will be filled by openssl_encrypt

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);
$encrypted = base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext.$tag);
```

**Decryption:**

```
$textToDecrypt = $_POST['message'];
$encrypted = base64_decode($textToDecrypt);
$password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);
$cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
$iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$tag_length = 16;
$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, $iv_len);
$ciphertext = substr($encrypted, $iv_len, -$tag_length);
$tag = substr($encrypted, -$tag_length);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
```

Comment: thank you, for the decryption I get an error for the last line 'Warning: openssl_decrypt(): Setting of IV length for AEAD mode failed' how do I correct this?

Comment: That means your `$_POST['message']` is empty. Check that you actually get the data in `$textToDecrypt`

Answer (score 3):

@Scribilicious
The problem here is that $iv and $tag are binary ($encrypted is base64). So it might be possible to have a '::' in the data.
So this might be better.

```
function encrypt($key, $data) {
    $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-gcm'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryptionKey, 0, $iv, $tag);
    return $encrypted . ':' . base64_encode($iv) . ':' . base64_encode($tag));
}

function decrypt($key, $data) {
    $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key);
    list($encryptedData, $iv, $tag) = explode(':', $data, 3);
    return openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryptionKey, 0, base64_decode($iv), base64_decode($tag));
}

$encrypt = encrypt('key', 'test data');
$decrypt = decrypt('key', $encrypt);

echo $encrypt . ' : ' . $decrypt;
```

Comment: return $encrypted . ':' . base64_encode($iv) . ':' . base64_encode($tag));

remove extra end paren

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
function encrypt($key, $data) {
    $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-gcm'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryptionKey, 0, $iv, $tag);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv . '::' . $tag);
}


function decrypt($key, $data) {
    $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key);
    list($encryptedData, $iv, $tag) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 3);
    return openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-gcm', $encryptionKey, 0, $iv, $tag);
}

$encrypt = encrypt('key', 'test data');
$decrypt = decrypt('key', $encrypt);

echo $encrypt . ' : ' . $decrypt;
```